# Why is segmentation fault given? C

Tags: c, function, pointers

I've tried writing this code and the two printf statements appear to give segmentation fault.
why isn't the output 5? what went wrong? and how to edit this code in  a way such that it prints 5?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* fun(int x){
    x=5;
    return &x;
}

int main() {
    int x = 3;
    int* p = fun(x);
    printf("%d",*(fun(x)));
    printf("%d",*p);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `fun` is returning a dangling pointer, since the variable it referred to no longer exists

Comment: You call a function that creates a variable.  Then you return a pointer to that variable.  When the function ends the variable is destroyed.  Now the pointer doesn't point anywhere.  If you try to use it literally anything can happen: the program could crash.  the compiler could just make up a number for the value of the variable, the computer could reboot, literally anything.

Comment: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

Comment: If you want to understand what can happen when you do something that is undefined behaviour (like using a pointer that doesn't point anywhere) have a look at this: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633